# Expected value of number of candles to last K days (probability)

Tags: probability, expected-value, geometric-distribution

I am trying to solve a question in probability which goes as follows:

There is a series of light bulbs on the street. Each light bulb may burn out with probability *p* every day and be out of use, independently of the other light bulbs.

a) What is the expected value of the number of days for which the first N bulbs will last?

b) What is the expected value for the number of light bulbs that will last for K days?

My answer for (a) is as follows:

For each $i\in N$ can denote random variable $Y_i$ to signify the number of days since $i-1$ bulbs burnt out until $i$ bulbs burnt out. We then get for each $i$ that $Y_i$ is geometrically distributed (dependent on $i$) and sum all these random variables to get the total number of days the bulbs lasted, lets denote it $Y$. We can then calculate the sum of the expected values of these variables and get $E[Y]$.

But as for (b), I don't know how to approach it - if I know that the bulbs have to last K days, what kind of random variables can I create so that their sum, or maybe maximum, I don't know, gives us the amount of time they survived together? And how can we get the expected value for that?

Comment: Hint: Define $X_i$ to be the indicator random variable that the $i^{\text{th}}$ bulb lasts for more than $K$ days.

Comment: But how do I know what the range of i is? I am trying to find out what the expected value of i is itself

Comment: $X_i$ will be defined for each $i \in \{1,2,\dots, N\}$. The total number of light bulbs that will last for $K$ days is given by $X = \sum_{i = 1}^N X_i$. Note that $X_i$ will be $1$ if the $i^{\text{th}}$ bulb lasts for $K$ days. Thus, summing it up will give you the required total number. Use linearity of expectation to obtain the required value.